# Angular - remote API's base URL mapping per customer

Tags: angular

Currently I have an `Angular 7.2.*` web application which is used against a single remote API URL. To be more clear, an example:

```
export const environment = {
    ...
    production: true,
    baseUrl: 'https://remote-api-url/'
}
```

This `environment.baseUrl` value is then used inside `*.service.ts` classes for data I/O operations.

Now, say I need to sell this application to multiple customers, how do I customize the `environment.baseUrl` **per customer**? Can this be done **without** having a separate build / separate `environment` file per customer?

I'd like to read your ideas on this.
The build result will be "packaged" as a Docker image.

Comment: Easiest way is when user logged in for example u set the base url per "customer"
or if for example you have customer.myurl.com/customer2.myurl.com
just get the type of customer and set the base url.

Comment: @Talg123 what you're suggesting seems like "maintaining a real in-house database of customer-URL mappings". Is this what you're saying?

Comment: @LppEdd, can you put baseUrl in a json file and distribute it separately from bundled app?

Comment: @ABOS yes, I could do that. But then how do I read it from the Angular application?

Comment: @LppEdd you can use http.get to fetch json

Comment: @ABOS I'm missing something, sorry. How can my Angular app, which is "working" from a browser, access a JSON file hosted on a remote server, without knowing its URL? (or where should it be hosted?)

Comment: @LppEdd, you just distribute that json file with build artifact for each customer.

Comment: @ABOS and wouldn't this be exactly like having a different `environment` file per customer?

Comment: @LppEdd, you don't need to rebuild, right? I am confused what you want to achieve

Comment: When you say sell, do you sell a build or do you sell an account in which they log in to?

Comment: @Chrillewoodz I'd sell a pre-built image. But I would like to "maintain" a single image, if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did was make a config file with an url:

```
{ "url": "yourURL" }
```

Add this to the assets map and then do:

```
this.http.get('./assets/config.json')
                .pipe(map(res => res))
                .toPromise() // or subscribe
                .then((config: any) => {
                    this.config = JSON.parse(config._body).url;
                });
```

Comment: Thanks! Basically the `assets` are resources which are always exposed to the outer world, right?

Comment: Yeah all files in the assets will be copied in production/your build.

Comment: What I did extra was make a promise around this code aswell cause sometime with a service it will recreate it and `this.config` will be undefined. Can also make a shared service,

Comment: Than I'd simply have to "copy" the custom file on the Docker volume, without having to do an image build, right?