# Angular - Synchronous XMLHttpRequest to load assets' JSON

Tags: javascript, angular, xmlhttprequest, assets

I had to use a `JSON` document as an asset, so I placed it under the

```
src/assets
```

folder. I need to load this `JSON` document at application startup, and it must be a synchronous operation, as the content of this `JSON` is used to correctly initialize other application's components.

What I've done is use `XMLHttpRequest`, as the Angular `HttpClient` is totally async.

```
const xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest()
xmlHttp.open('GET', this.assetUrl, false)   <-- false to produce a synchronous call
xmlHttp.send()

const configuration = xmlHttp.responseText
return JSON.parse(configuration)
```

However the browser console throws a warning

> [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is
>   deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's
>   experience.

Can I still use this piece of code, or should I think of something else?
Being that the asset folder is packed with the application, there is no detrimental effect, I suppose.

---

Additional information. This questions comes after [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54652815/angular-remote-apis-base-url-mapping-per-customer).
For example, the JSON document contains an `URL`, and it should be used this way

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpMyService {
   private readonly baseUrl: string
   ...

   public constructor(
      configurationService: ConfigurationService,
      private readonly httpClient: HttpClient,
      private readonly logger: NGXLogger
   ) {
      // Get url from JSON document inside assets 
      this.baseUrl = configurationService.getConfigurationSync().url
   }

   ...
}
```

Comment: `it must be a synchronous operation, as the content of this JSON is used to correctly initialize other application's components` I'm not sure this is the case tbh; why can't you init the other components in the success callback? - side note: a different approach would be to include the JSON in your main index.html on the server, using `var config = { ... };` so it doesn't have to be loaded.

Comment: @ChrisG I added more information to the question. You should be able to get the context better now.

Comment: You can solve it with async/await and HttpClient. If I understand it well.

Comment: I don't see how this necessitates a sync request. Load config -> when async has finished, instantiate HttpMyService using loaded url. I'm not saying it's a simple change, I'm saying it's easily possible.

Comment: @JosefKatič if you think transforming the `HttpClient` return `Observable` to a `Promise` and using async/await may help, feel free to answer the question. I'll gladly accept every suggestion.

Comment: @ChrisG the `HttpMyService` is instantiated and provided automatically by Angular (dependency injection). But feel free to expand on that point. I may be missing something here.

Comment: Did a quick google search and found [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/angular-how-to-editable-config-files/), does that help?

Comment: @ChrisG this seems something I need to try out! Thanks Chris. I'll let you know if this works.

Answer (score 1):

You can use HttpClient and async/await, as mentioned by @Josef Katič

service:

```
getJson() {
    return this.http.get(url).toPromise();
}
```

component:

```
async init() {
    let data = await service.getJson();
}
```